# Absolutely positioned DIV filling up entire page

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me why the absolutely positioned red DIV isn't filling the entire page and how to fix it? It's only filling the viewport. I've seen quite a few of the same questions, but either the person's code is so messed up it's no wonder it doesn't work, or the solutions just don't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/YysvK/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 999; background-color: #f00; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason, even after specifying position, width, and height on the body element, this doesn't work, but wrapping everything in a DIV just inside of body and setting that to `position: relative` works.

http://jsfiddle.net/k5uZ5/

I'm still not sure why `<body>` isn't behaving like other elements. If someone could explain that I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Change the position from absolute to fixed.

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: 999; background-color: #f00; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YysvK/2/)**

Comment: That's what I typically use, but in this case I'd like to keep everything contained in a DIV instead of putting a fixed DIV outside of it, and there is scrolling involved, so position: fixed won't work in that case.

Comment: I guess it's just not possible? Technically I have no idea why not. Even setting a fixed height on body won't work. Anyway, I guess a fixed position is the only way so I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: If you use fixed you will not achieve the effect you want in iPad Mobile Safari. The other answer reaches a larger share of mobile devices.

Comment: I accomplished it by using a fixed div with an inner div with overflow: scroll. Works fine on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to have the following:

```
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#f00;
```

Comment: That doesn't work, Alex. Did you try it? `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` should work as well, but neither of these work on the `body` element. I put your CSS into a Fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/JyN3c/

Comment: Ok, my comment above gave me an idea. For same reason even with specifying position, width, and height on the body element, it doesn't work. Using a container works. I'll add the answer to this question.

Comment: In this situation your absolute position div pics up the height/size of the window, best solution would be to either go for psition:fixed; or reproach your solution either looking into a quick JavaScript solution or depending on your HTML structure different layout options if you want to stick with position:absolute;